# How can I write script, that shows message if found wanted .js file and then execute it?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing research over *how to include .js file in another .js file*. I found many different solutions, that would suit me. But the problem is, that; as I mentioned in title, I want my app to show message, when the script is found, and then execute it, not execute script of included .js file first, and show message after that. Is there any possible way, I could do that? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here's what I tried so far, and what I found the best solution:

```js
//This is vanila JavaScript

function loadApp(url, callback){
    var script = document.createElement("script"); 
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    script.src = url; 
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code you've tried so far. Also, have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So what do you do to execute it? Really unclear what you are doing.

Comment: @TomM I looked at it ,and ok, ok, I'll show you what I tried so far in a moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var showMessageAndExecute = (scriptUrl) => {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
         if (this.status==200){
           // Show Found Message
           alert("Script Found");
           // Execute the found script
           var fn = Function(xhttp.responseText);
           fn();
         }
         else {
            // Show Not Found Message
             alert("Script Not Found");
         }
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", scriptUrl, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

Comment: This script looks very nice, but it's 11 PM here in Poland, so I'm gonna check your code later, cheers :D

Comment: **IT WORKS**! Thank you very much dude :D

Comment: I also tipped it for the best one out there 